# Adding (minutes / hours / days / months / years) to date when INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add (minutes / hours / days / months / years) to date in INSERT

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(value,expire) VALUES("Some text", NOW() + 4 MONTHS)
```

(SQL query or in PHP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `DATE_ADD()` function like so:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table (value, expire) 
VALUES ("Some text", DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH));
```

It also works with other intervals such as the intervals that you requested in your question

You can find more about the `DATE_ADD()` function here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `interval` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(value, expire)
    VALUES('Some text', NOW() + INTERVAL 4 MONTHS);
```

Comment: Is that valid SQL ? Have never seen the `+` sign replace the `DATE_ADD` function

Comment: @FMashiro Yes; you even [linked to the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) in your answer: I.e. from the manual `date + INTERVAL expr unit`

Comment: My bad, hadn't seen that part yet.